# Change the owner of Disk(Read-write permissions disabled)[Ubuntu 18.04][HDD File System: NTFS]

Tags: disk, read-write

I have an external HDD which was working fine previously. But after connecting it to a windows system suddenly it's read-write permissions have changed and I am unable to write data to it when on a linux or mac operating system. I have looked for other answers but couldn't find a legit solution. Can anyone please help me..

I have tried changing the owner of files with

```
    sudo chown -R -v username:staff *
```

But terminal ended up showing:

```
   chown: MyFolder/ABC.mp4: Read-only file system
   chown: MyFolder: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to just make a comment and suggest that you need to provide more information such as the Linux distro, the filesystem, how you are connecting the HDD, and more details. However, I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment. Therefore, I will do my best to answer with the limited info you provided.

I suggest that the first step you need to take is to look in your system's log files. If you are running a systemd Linux distro, connect your disk, then run this command in the terminal:

```
journalctl -r
```

That will show you recent log entries.

Next you can check for damage to the HDD. Find the device id with a command similar to `lsblk`. Use that id to run a tool like smartctl. In this example, your external disk is sdb.

```
smartctl -i /dev/sdb
```

You should expect to see a result similar to:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

If you are running Gnome, you may have the Gnome disk utility GUI tool that you can use to check your HDD's health.

Comment: My HDD running fine on Windows though

Comment: Your question still doesn't include enough info. What have you tried that didn't work? Did you try these two things?
https://askubuntu.com/a/958611
https://askubuntu.com/a/70304